# Link multiple docker compose files residing in nested folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 related projects in 2 different folders. The folders have docker compose files in 2 nested folders - Outer and Inner.
The inner folder has a docker-compose.yml and its dependent yml files. It also has its .env file.
The outer folder has a docker-compose.yml. The env file just mentions COMPOSE_FILE and tries to link the 2 docker-compose.yml files with the proper path mentioned.
COMPOSE_FILE=App1.yml:inner/docker-compose.yml

When I run "docker compose up" from the outer folder, I had expected the App1.yml to be run and then inner/docker-compose.yml to be run by considering all the dependencies in the inner folder and it should start all containers listed in the docker-compose files of both folders. But it is not working. It gives error that it is not able to locate the dependencies which are listed in the inner/docker-compose.yml as it is trying to search for it in the outer folder. Its also not able to get the env details from the inner folder. Is there any way to resolve this issue?